# AWS DNS propagate in Route 53 taking too much time

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-route53

I create static site in s3 , and create records in route 53 and CNAME value is s3 site url

Its working fine, site available on browser

If I am doing these steps manually DNS propagate will work quickly but taking for around 30 minutes if I am doingit  through AWS-SDK nodejs from my application

```
let changeResourceRecordSetsParams = {
    ChangeBatch: {
        Changes: [
            {
                Action: action,
                ResourceRecordSet: {
                    Name: domain,
                    TTL: 60,
                    Type: "CNAME",
                     
                    ResourceRecords: [
                        {
                          Value: s3BucketName
                        }
                      ]

                }
            }
        ]
    },
    HostedZoneId: "***"
};
```

Is there any difference between doing manually and doing with aws-sdk ? How can I avoid this delay ?